# Laurent expansion of $z^{-1/2}/(z^2+1)$

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to know residue at z=0 to evaluate integral $z^{-1/2}/(z^2+1)$ on small semicircle around origin. How to do that? thank you.

I need that because I want to calculate $\int_0^\infty 1/(\sqrt{x}(1+x^2)) dx$ by complex analysis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function has a branch point at $z=0$, so there is no such thing as a residue there.

EDIT: 
If you want $\oint_C z^{-1/2}/(z^2+1)\; dz$ where $C$ is a semicircle of radius $r < 1$ in the upper half plane centred at $0$ (using the principal branch of the square root), the parametrization $z = r e^{i\theta}$, $0 < \theta < \pi$ makes this
$$ \int_0^\pi \frac{i r^{1/2}}{r^2 e^{2i\theta}+1} d\theta$$
and it's easy to see this goes to $0$ as $r \to 0$ (in fact it's bounded by a constant times $r^{1/2}$).

Comment: so integral on semicircle is zero?

Comment: No, that's not what I meant.  "There is no such thing" does not mean "the thing is $0$".

Comment: could you help me which closed counter is suitable for this integral? I used two semicircle with $r<1<R$ and two legs connecting them. Then using Jordan lemma which you said is non applicable here